# What inputs to give to a trained neural network?

Tags: neural-networks, echo-state-network

Real beginner on neural networks here, so my apologies if the answer is obvious!

I'm learning Echo State Neural networks for non-linear function modelling and I'm struggling to understand why sometimes a simple vector with one's ([1,1,...,1]) is given as input both in the train phase and the predictions themselves.

I've seen this happen in an example where an ESN is used to learn the Mackey-Glass chaotic system (https://github.com/cknd/pyESN/blob/master/mackey.ipynb) but I just don't understand why it works.

Usually, performing a typical train/test split on the X and y data, one uses the X_test part as input to calculate the predictions to be compared with y_test. In the example above, both in the train and test parts they simply give a vector of one's in the same dimensionality as X.

I would understand that something of the sort could be given to predict future values when no data is available but even then, I would pick the previous value, predict the next one, use the prediction to predict the second one, and so on.

Comment: Your current title "What inputs to give to a trained neural network?" doesn't reflect your **specific** question or problem. You're not asking about any neural network, but a specific type of NN.